# Serialize Class Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I’m trying to serialize class but I can’t do it.
I have a class below:

```
public class DadosTitulo
{
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public string numeroCpfCnpj { get; set; }
    public string logradouro { get; set; }
    public string numero { get; set; }
    public string complemento { get; set; }
    public string bairro { get; set; }
    public string cep { get; set; }
    public string municipio { get; set; }
    public string uf { get; set; }
    public double valor { get; set; }
    public string numeroDocumento { get; set; }
    public string dataVencimento { get; set; }
    public string celularDestino { get; set; }
    public bool registroProducao { get; set; }
}
```

And in my MainPage.xaml.cs I have:

```
private async void btnAdicionar_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var retorno = "";
    var titulo = new DadosTitulo
    {
        nome = txtNome.Text,
        numeroCpfCnpj = txtNumeroCpfCnpj.Text,
        logradouro = txtLogradouro.Text,
        numero = txtNumero.Text,
        complemento = txtComplemento.Text,
        bairro = txtBairro.Text,
        cep = txtCep.Text,
        municipio = txtMunicipio.Text,
        uf = txtUF.Text,
        valor = Convert.ToDouble(txtValor.Text),
        numeroDocumento = txtNumeroDocumento.Text,
        dataVencimento = DataVencimento.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
        celularDestino = txtDddCelularDestino.Text + txtNumCelularDestino.Text,
        registroProducao = RegistraProducao
    };
    var registroService = new RegistroBoletoService();
    retorno = registroService.RegistrarBoleto(titulo);
    await DisplayAlert("Json", retorno, "OK");
}
```

Property Values from MainPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AppRegistraBoletoXF"
             x:Class="AppRegistraBoletoXF.MainPage">

    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Registra Boleto" TextColor="Indigo" FontSize="Medium" />
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Informe os dados do Título:" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Small" />
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout>
            <Entry x:Name="txtNome" Placeholder="Nome" HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                    VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HeightRequest="35" WidthRequest="300" FontSize="Small"/>
            <Entry x:Name="txtNumeroCpfCnpj" Placeholder="CPF/CNPJ" HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                    VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HeightRequest="35" WidthRequest="300" FontSize="Small" />
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Entry x:Name="txtLogradouro" Placeholder="Logradouro" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" 
                        HeightRequest="35" WidthRequest="160" FontSize="Small" />
                <Entry x:Name="txtNumero" Placeholder="Número" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" 
                        HeightRequest="35" WidthRequest="50" FontSize="Small" />
                <Entry x:Name="txtComplemento" Placeholder="Complemento" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" 
                        HeightRequest="35" WidthRequest="90" FontSize="Small" />
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Entry x:Name="txtBairro" Placeholder="Bairro" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" 
                        HeightRequest="35" WidthRequest="180" FontSize="Small" />
                <Entry x:Name="txtCep" Placeholder="CEP" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" 
                        HeightRequest="35" WidthRequest="120" FontSize="Small" />
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Entry x:Name="txtMunicipio" Placeholder="Município" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" 
                        HeightRequest="35" WidthRequest="250" FontSize="Small" />
                <Entry x:Name="txtUF" Placeholder="UF" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" 
                        HeightRequest="35" WidthRequest="50" FontSize="Small" />
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Entry x:Name="txtDddCelularDestino" Placeholder="DDD" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" 
                        HeightRequest="35" WidthRequest="50" FontSize="Small" />
                <Entry x:Name="txtNumCelularDestino" Placeholder="Celular Destino" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" 
                        HeightRequest="35" WidthRequest="250" FontSize="Small" />
            </StackLayout>

            <Entry x:Name="txtNumeroDocumento" Placeholder="Número do Título" HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                    VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HeightRequest="35" WidthRequest="300" FontSize="Small"/>
            <Entry x:Name="txtValor" Placeholder="Valor do Título" HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                    VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HeightRequest="35" WidthRequest="300" FontSize="Small"/>

            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Text="Registro em Produção: " TextColor="Black" FontSize="Small" HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                    VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
                <DatePicker DateSelected="DataSelecionada" HorizontalOptions="Start"  VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                    <DatePicker.Format>dd/MM/yyyy</DatePicker.Format>
                </DatePicker>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Text="Registro em Produção: " TextColor="Black" FontSize="Small" HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                    VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
                <Switch IsToggled="False"  Toggled="RegistrarProducao" HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                    VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
            </StackLayout>


            <Button HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HeightRequest="40" Text="Registrar Título" 
                    Clicked="btnAdicionar_Clicked" FontSize="Small"/>
        </StackLayout>

    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

In RegistroBoletoService:

```
public string RegistrarBoleto(DadosTitulo dadosTitulo)
{
    var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dadosTitulo);

    return data;
}
```

data allways return “{}”: [image: Result from MainPage.xaml.cs]
[image: Json on device]

I have made a test calling RegistroBoletoService from Console Project, in the same Solution, and the result was as expected: data contains json 
[image: Result From Console Project]
[image: Json from Console Project]

The interesting point that I noticed: when I have instantiated the class in MainPage.xaml.cs the behavior was diferent from Console Project, with Non-Public Members in the class: [image: Call from MainPage.xaml.cs]

Console Instantiate: [image: Call from Console Project]

I think that this is the problem, anyone have an idea what is it happening ? Why when I have instantiated the class in the MainPage I get different behavior from the Console ?

Thanks a lot and sorry my English.

PS.: Project in .NET Standard; I’m not using MVVM in this case; I tried testing with the linker SDK Assemblies Only and None.

Comment: Where are you changing the values of properties of DadosTitulo class?

Comment: In this example I didn't change the values in anywhere, I just intended to showproblem  with  Non-public Members in the class. However I have made like example and the result was the same:
private async void btnAdicionar_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 var retorno = "";
 var titulo = new DadosTitulo
 {
  nome = txtNome.Text,
  numeroCpfCnpj = txtNumeroCpfCnpj.Text,
  logradouro = txtLogradouro.Text,
  numero = txtNumero.Text,
  .... }

Comment: Ok I am asking this because you are getting null values because your properties are pretty much empty (null), can you edit this question and provide us the code both from xaml and c# where you are setting the values to this class properties.

Comment: Did you try to get rid of the interface inheritance and run the code with the concrete class references? I'm thinkin' about the possibility of the serialization method is inferring the interface type instead of the concrete class

Comment: Hi @DiegoRafaelSouza, I tried with a concret class and the result was the same. I'm editing the post for concret class and change the values of properties, like as Almir Vuk  suggested. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @AlmirVuk...I edited the question ...Thanks for help me.